# Add_row using inside Rest Api endpoint - Wordpress ACF

Tags: wordpress, rest, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

Im trying to add rows from data that the user will send from http request, and insert it into a certain repeater field.

Right now, I’m having troubles with the function that look like that:

```
function add_row_to_direction() {
    $row =
        array(
            'title'            => "Test Title",
            'directions_group' => array(
                array(
                    'direction' => "Test Direction"
                )
            )
        );

    add_row( "directions", $row, 365 );
}
```

The problem is when i add this test function to the rest api endpoint callback function it does not happens, and if i just call the function inside functions.php all works as expected.

I hope you guys can help me,

Thanks a lot,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 methods to add the row.

Method 1:

1. make sure you load your function when all plugins is fully loaded. There is high possibility that your function is getting executed before ACF is fully loaded. So add the below line to your code:

   ```
   add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'add_row_to_direction' );

   function add_row_to_direction() {

   $row =

   array(

       'title'            => "Test Title",

       'directions_group' => array(

           array(

               'direction' => "Test Direction"

           )

       )

   );

   add_row( "directions", $row, 365 );

   }
   ```

Method 2:

1. Expose the Field Group to rest API within ACF.
2. If you are targeting a custom post type you have to go and add

   ```
    'show_in_rest' => true
   ```

   within the function, you register that post type.
3. Carry out either a POST or a PUT request.